# PHP MySQL Json add a field

Tags: php, mysql, json

And directly my next PHP-MySQL question :D

I try to add a field to my json.

Now I'm doing this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json[$table][]=$row;
    }
}
```

But now I want to add a extra field to my row and put it with in json. So, if I'm using the json later, that the extra field is in the json like the fields from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the extra field to the row before inserting the latter into the array.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row['extraField'] = 42; // <-- here
    $json[$table][] = $row;
}
```